# update index in Solr, error: required field in SolrSchema not found in DataConfig

Tags: mysql, indexing, solr

I'm trying to update my index, but I keep on getting the error:

> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter
>   verifyWithSchema INFO: UPC is a
>   required field in SolrSchema . But not
>   found in DataConfigfound in DataConfig

I can't figure out why it's complainting, since:

1. the first time I ran the import, it worked fine, and the only thing I changed was add a few fields (columns) to schema.xml
2. the table I am querying indeed has a UPC column. Here is what my data-config.xml looks like:

   ```
   <dataConfig>
     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
         driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product" 
         user="root" 
         password="some_password"/>
     <document>
       <entity name="product" 
          query="select * from productdetails">
       </entity>
     </document>
    </dataConfig>
   ```

But again, the interesting part is that the import worked a second ago, but fails on re-import. I'm hoping somebody has had this problem before. If not, maybe someone can suggest other things to check for?

Comment: Did you do a full import both times? If solr is missing a required field the second time you run this, it sounds like something changed in your content or schema between the executions

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that when DataImportHandler starts it checks its config against your loaded schema. It is not an error, merely a warning. To remove it you have to add a specific field in your import config with a name that matches your required field.

This is not the cause of your failed reimport as this is simply a warning.